# What is the correct XDR syntax for a variable-length array of strings?

Tags: rpc, rfc, xdr

I am reading the [RFC 4506](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506) to understand the XDR data definition language.

It mentions that variable-length arrays are declared as follows.

```
 type-name identifier<m>;
```

It also mentions that variable-length strings are declared as follows.

```
 string object<m>;
```

Unfortunately, the only way it shows to have a variable length array of strings is a linked list, which seems very manual.

```
struct *stringlist {
    string item<>;
    stringlist next;
};
```

Is there a more simple or more correct way to declare a variable-length array of strings?

Comment: Can you check if my answer is correct?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni, This is a somewhat dated question, but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `typedef` keyword.

> `typedef` does not declare any data either, but serves to define new
>      identifiers for declaring data.  The syntax is:
>
> ```
>     typedef declaration;
> ```
>
> The new type name is actually the variable name in the declaration
>      part of the typedef.  For example, the following defines a new type
>      called "eggbox" using an existing type called "egg":
>
> ```
>     typedef egg eggbox[DOZEN];
> ```

We can define a `variableLengthString` type with

```
typedef string variableLengthString<>;
```

and then declare a `variableLengthString` array with

```
variableLengthString object<>;
```

Comment: In practice the second typedef was not necessary all the time, (you can just declare an variable-length array of `variableLengthString` objects directly), but this answer is correct regardless.

Comment: @merlin2011 I've modified my answer according to your remark.